# Cryptography - AES and DES S-boxes

Tags: cryptography, aes, des

I am working on some cryptology revision exercises for university (in preparation for an exam) and this question has me puzzled:

Most block cipher implementations treat S-boxes as lookup tables.
DES uses 8 S-boxes which each take in 6 bits and output 4 bits. AES uses only
one S-box which takes in 8 bits and outputs 8 bits. **How much storage is required
in each case?**

I... have no idea? I'm not sure exactly what this question is asking. I feel like I may be missing some concept about storage and s-boxes?

If anyone could shed some light on this, it would be great!
Thanks.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about cryptography. This question belongs on crypto.stackexchange.com

Comment: not off topic -> implementation detail

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems a bit of a strange question, but here's how I think I'd approach it:

If implemented as a lookup-table, it's basically just an array with the "lookup" just being indexing into the array.

The number of array elements must therefore correspond to the number of distinct values that the input can take, e.g. if the S-box input is 8-bit, then there are 2<sup>8</sup> = 256 possible input values.

The size of the array elements themselves correspond to the number of output bits. Now, we generally can't define arrays with elements smaller than 8-bits (1 byte), but we'll presume that it's possible to encode the outputs such that we can construct an array with no "wasted" space (as would occur if we had to store say, a 4-bit value in an 8-bit array element).

With this in mind we should be able to calculate the storage as follows:

```
Storage (in bytes) = Number of S-boxes x 2Number of input bits x (Number of output bits / 8)
```

So:

```
DES = 8 x 26 x (4 / 8) = 256 bytes
```

```
AES = 1 x 28 x (8 / 8) = 256 bytes
```

Comment: Hello! thank you for answering. I think it's a strange question too.

I'm just trying to figure out why you are diving the output by 8?
(and sorry if the answer is very obvious but this is my first cryptography subject)

Comment: The division by 8 gives you a result in bytes rather than bits.

Comment: OH OF COURSE. right that makes sense. I think this answer matches the concepts that they introduced in the lectures so I think I get it now! thank you so much :)

Comment: This is the reason I try to use `Byte.SIZE` in Java instead of just `8`.